# how to get updated id in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm new to Codeigniter, but learning from web,
actually i got stuck with a unknown proble.

im inserting data into the database throw the model, and fetching back the data into form.

but when i'm updating the form i want to return the updated id.

i used `$user_id = $this->db->insert_id();` but this is for getting insert id,

even i tried this

```
 $this->db->where('id_colum', $student_id);
 $this->db->update('table_name', $data);
 $user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
 return $user_id;
```

help me out,
Thanks for everything..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
$this->db->where('id_colum', $student_id);
$this->db->update('table_name', $data);
$updated_status = $this->db->affected_rows();

if($updated_status):
    return $student_id;
else:
    return false;
endif;
```

If it is updated, then return back that **$student_id**. :)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Mr. Imran.
but i tried this, but it returning 1 to me.

Comment: You need to understand that if updating process occur, then it will return back the `student_id` else it will return false. Try change your data and see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('id_colum', $student_id);
$updatedId = $this->db->get('table_name')->row()->id;

$this->db->where('id', $updatedId);
$this->db->update('table_name', $data);

if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
   return $updatedId;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: It would be more clear if you would add comments on what and why you are doing here